# Duplicate records appear in database

Tags: ios, objective-c, mongodb, http, httprequest

The server side is normal with correct debug messages printing out in the right amount. However, in my database (using Mongodb), there are always "unstable" duplicate records appear every time.

I doubt it may be due to how I should configure the HTTP request? It might be sending multiple requests. For now:

```
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest addValue:@"image/png" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
//    [urlRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
//    [urlRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
//    [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:3000];
```

I doubt it may be the TimeoutInterval. However, no matter I comment out the bottom part or not, it does not make a difference now.

Any suggestions on how I should avoid duplicate requests sent so that they create duplicate records in the database?

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling the method to send the data multiple times by mistake? Where are you calling that from?

Comment: @Eeshwar I'm sure it only calls the times I want with debug msgs printed.